# Can I create a static class of outer class and use an inner static class as the category of outer class to access to specific methods?

Tags: c#

I am asking a question about how can I create a static class of outer class which is non-static, and make a static class act as the category of outer class for accessing to specific methods. I do not want users to create an instance of a **static class** of outer class.

Example:

```
// OUTER_CLASS.INNER_CLASS.METHODS
var Poinet = new Human(); // OUTER CLASS
Poinet.Eye.Blink(); // Eye is a static class (inner).
Poinet.Mouth.Eat(); // Mouth is a static class.
```

The reason I am making an inner class **static** is to prevent users from creating an instance of inner class.

Example of what I don't want to happen:

```
var Poinet = new Human();
Poinet.Eye eyes = new Poinet.Eye();
eyes.Blink(); // I don't like the way these are implemented.
```

Is it possible to approach these problems? OR is there any other way of implementing a class that acts as the category of another class for accessing to specific methods?

Comment: Vaguely describing you goals isn't as good as presenting a *compilable attempt* and presenting the specific errors you've seen

Comment: The answer is no, you can't reference a static member or inner type from an instance variable. Now that you know that, what other options are you open to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't reference a static member or inner type from an instance variable. There are ways to keep users from *creating* the inner type, or from modifying the member, but not from *referencing* it.  In other words, if a user can do this:

```
Poinet.Eye.Blink();
```

Then they can do this

```
var eye = Poinet.Eye;
eye.Blink();
```

But you can make it so that users either can't create an `Eye`, or change the value of `Eye`, or both.

Also note that `static` is probably not what you want anyway, since `static` members are "shared" by all instances, so in this example  the `Eye` definitely belongs to the `Person` instance.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
public class Human
{
    public _Eye Eye {get;} = new _Eye();
    public _Mouth Mouth {get;} = new _Mouth();

    public class _Eye {
        internal _Eye() { return; }  // don't let users create this type
        public void Blink() { return; } 
    }
    public class _Mouth {
        internal _Mouth() { return; } // don't let users create this type
        public void Eat() { return; } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, this is exactly what I wanted, however, there are some problems with this. You could create an instance of Eye by using the outer class name instead of object, for example: var eyes = new Human.Eyes(); which I don't want that because when you call the method of eyes, the method does not know who eyes belong to (i.e the object of human is missing), therefore causing problems, when you call the method, the method need to get its parent class (i.e the object of human) to function properly. Is there other way to fix this current problem?

Comment: If you make the constructor `internal` (as I did in the example) then you can't create an instance outside of the assembly. You could also make it `private` if you only want the Human class to use it.

Comment: Alright, thanks again, I have another question, how can I access the parent class (outer class) from inner class?

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I am making an inner class static is to prevent users from creating an instance of inner class.

That's not what `static` is for, that's just a side effect of it. What you actually seem to want, for some reason, is singletons. Something like this:

```
class O
{
    public class IT
    {
        internal IT() { }
        public void F() { }
    }
    public IT I { get; } = new();
}

// called as:
var o = new O();
o.I.F();
```

Comment: I am somewhat concerned by your proposal that `Human.Eye` be a singleton.

Comment: Well, you can have two instances for each eye. Note that I didn't use his names. Also, cyclops lives matter too!